# Drupal SEO page titles

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to list a few games, each, on individual pages. While a game page is opened into a new window the head title of page (`< title>`) is set to games page header (`< h1>` My Game). Also to list all game types I am using quick tabs.

From 12 types of games only at 2 of them the title is settled correctly and my problem is that I don't know from where it comes. I have tried to `var_dump()` all the headers and all of them are returning the same thing "Game" not the title/heading from db.

Where should I look or what would be the next step ?

```
$metaTitle = $page['content']['metatags']['global']['title']['#attached']['metatag_set_preprocess_variable'][0][2];
$metaTitle = str_replace(' | SuperCasino.com', '', $metaTitle);
```

Where should I look or what would be the next step ?

Here is my preprocess page code

```
function desktop_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
    if (isset($vars['node_title'])) {
        $vars['title'] = $vars['node_title'];
    }
    // Adding a class to #page in wireframe mode
    if (theme_get_setting('wireframe_mode')) {
        $vars['classes_array'][] = 'wireframe-mode';
    }
    // Adding classes wether #navigation is here or not
    if (!empty($vars['main_menu']) or !empty($vars['sub_menu'])) {
        $vars['classes_array'][] = 'with-navigation';
    }
    if (!empty($vars['secondary_menu'])) {
        $vars['classes_array'][] = 'with-subnav';
    }
    // Page template suggestions based off of content types
    if (isset($vars['theme_hook_suggestions']['node'])) {
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__type__'. $vars['node']->type;
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = "page__node__" . $vars['node']->nid;
    }

    // Add first/last classes to node listings about to be rendered.
    if (isset($vars['page']['content']['system_main']['nodes'])) {
        // All nids about to be loaded (without the #sorted attribute).
        $nids = element_children($vars['page']['content']['system_main']['nodes']);
        // Only add first/last classes if there is more than 1 node being rendered.
        if (count($nids) > 1) {
            $first_nid = reset($nids);
            $last_nid = end($nids);
            $first_node = $vars['page']['content']['system_main']['nodes'][$first_nid]['#node'];
            $first_node->classes_array = array('first');
            $last_node = $vars['page']['content']['system_main']['nodes'][$last_nid]['#node'];
            $last_node->classes_array = array('last');
        }
    }
    //var_dump($vars['theme_hook_suggestions']);die();

   // Page template suggestions based off URL alias
    if (module_exists('path')) {
        //$alias = drupal_get_path_alias(str_replace('/edit','',$_GET['q']));
        $alias = request_path();

        if ($alias != $_GET['q']) {
            //echo'here';die;
            $template_filename = 'page';
            foreach (explode('/', $alias) as $path_part) {
                $template_filename = $template_filename . '__' . str_replace('-','_',$path_part);
                $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = $template_filename;
                //var_dump($template_filename);
            } 

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use drupal_set_title(YOUR_TITLE) for the different pages.

```
    drupal_set_title($title = NULL, $output = CHECK_PLAIN)
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_title/7

From the theme level, you can use this code in your template.php:

```
function MYTHEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
    $vars['title'] = $custom_title';
    $vars['head_title'] = $custom_title;
}
```

For Drupal 7 its is :
    $vars['site_name']

Comment: the title is comming dynamical from db and sets the header page.

Comment: yes in that case as well, this method should work, get the title from the DB and use this method to set the page title. It should work fine. Are you using a custom module?

Comment: I am not using any custom module, the theme of website is made in phptemplate and it shows only $header_title;

Comment: ok then from the theme level you can also change your page title like this. Use this code in your template.php.

    function MYTHEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
        $vars['title'] = $custom_title';
        $vars['head_title'] = $custom_title;
    }

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare desktop_preprocess_page() this is the message that came through

Comment: refer: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7

Comment: I have been trying the suggested function from drupal api but has no effect at all.

Comment: Problem fixed, it was taxonomies who was overwriting the URLS